# Android Data Binding Application namespace for attribute app:itemIconTint will be ignored

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Since few hours I'm stuck on an issue with Data Binding, specifically using @BindingAdapter for a custom binding.

I have a BottomNavigationView and I want to bind `itemIconTint` and `itemTextColor` to load a specific ColorStateList depending of a boolean.

So I have the following XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="mypackage.HomeActivity">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="utils"
            type="mypackage.model.Utils" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@{utils.lawyer ? @color/greyish_brown : @color/white}"
            app:itemIconTint="@{utils.lawyer ? @colorStateList/nav_item_color_state_lawyer : @colorStateList/nav_item_color_state_user}"
            app:itemTextColor="@{utils.lawyer ? @colorStateList/nav_item_color_state_lawyer : @colorStateList/nav_item_color_state_user}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

And here is the class Utils :

```
public class Utils {

    private boolean lawyer;

    public boolean isLawyer() {
        return lawyer;
    }

    public void setLawyer(boolean lawyer) {
        this.lawyer = lawyer;
    }


    @BindingAdapter({"app:itemIconTint"})
    public static void setItemIconTint(BottomNavigationView view, ColorStateList colorStateList) {

        view.setItemIconTintList(colorStateList);
    }


    @BindingAdapter({"app:itemTextColor"})
    public static void setItemTextColor(BottomNavigationView view, ColorStateList colorStateList) {

        view.setItemTextColor(colorStateList);
    }
}
```

So my goal is to load a different `ColorStateList`depending of the boolean `lawyer`. With that the `BottomNavigationView` will have a dynamic design.

When I compile I have this bug :

```
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: processing adapters
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: building generational class cache
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: loaded item android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessBindable$IntermediateV1@49d08673 from file
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: loaded item android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions$IntermediateV2@4e48888f from file
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: loaded item android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore$IntermediateV3@11787d5f from file
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/.../model/Utils.java:27: warning: Application namespace for attribute app:itemIconTint will be ignored.
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err]     public static void setItemIconTint(BottomNavigationView view, ColorStateList colorStateList) {
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err]                        ^
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: STORE addBindingAdapter itemIconTint setItemIconTint(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView,int)
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: BINARY created method desc 2 mypackage.model.Utils setItemIconTint, setItemIconTint(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView,android.content.res.ColorStateList)
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/.../model/Utils.java:34: warning: Application namespace for attribute app:itemTextColor will be ignored.
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err]     public static void setItemTextColor(BottomNavigationView view, ColorStateList colorStateList) {
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err]                        ^
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: STORE addBindingAdapter itemTextColor setItemTextColor(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView,android.content.res.ColorStateList)
14:13:42.540 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: BINARY created method desc 2 mypackage.Utils setItemTextColor, setItemTextColor(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView,android.content.res.ColorStateList)
```

Thanks for your help !

Edit : the two differents color files come from folder Color 
[image]

Edit 2 : as @tynn said, Android Data Binding doesn't know about resource types. So for Color ressource `@color`has to be replaced by `@colorStateList. So I did the change, and my custom BindingAdapter has been updated too to received a ColorStateList instead of an int. The issue is the same

Issue resolved : No need for custom BindingAdapter because data binding auto generate setter based on existing setter in each class (check on [Attribute Setters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#attribute_setters)). My issue was weird and because of R file, it was badly generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up colors and color state lists. The former is just an `int` while the latter should be a `ColorStateList`. At the end of the data bindings [Expression Language](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#expression_language) documentation you find that you need to use `@colorStateList` instead of `@color`. Also `@color` results in a color int, not in a color resource.

For your adapters you'd also have to use the attribute name without namespace.

But eventually in your case you'd only have to set `app:itemTextColor` and `app:itemIconTintList` without defining an adapter. The processor will choose the correct setters [`setItemTextColor(ColorStateList)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setItemTextColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) and [`setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setItemIconTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) for you.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@{utils.lawyer ? @color/greyish_brown : @color/white}"
    app:itemIconTintList="@{utils.lawyer ? @colorStateList/nav_item_color_state_lawyer : @colorStateList/nav_item_color_state_user}"
    app:itemTextColor="@{utils.lawyer ? @colorStateList/nav_item_color_state_lawyer : @colorStateList/nav_item_color_state_user}"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'm going to check how I can update my custom BindingAdapter. Also there is no default setter for some attribute, and that's the case for `itemIconTint` and `itemTextColor`. So, in any case I have to create one to fit my need

Comment: Yes I am, using : android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: I did it and it's not working (even after cleaning / building again). Also `itemIconTintList` is causing a different issue. I truly think the good attribute is `itemIconTint`. But even with that and deleting my custom BindingAdapter I have the issue I told you (about missing setter) : 
`Error:(38, 33) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:itemIconTint' with parameter type android.content.res.ColorStateList on android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView. `

Comment: I just want to highlight you are right on one thing : I have to use `@colorStateList` instead of `@color`. I tried to update my BindingAdapter to use a `ColorStateList` instead of int, but I have the same issue

Comment: Readup on [Attribute Setters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#attribute_setters). Which is the different issue with `itemIconTintList`? Did it work with `app:itemTextColor`?

Comment: `itemIconTint` is the XML attribute for the method `setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList)` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#attr_android.support.design:itemIconTint

And if I delete the custom BindingAdapter and keep only `app:itemTextColor` the error is different : 

`checking method api for setItemTextColor, class:android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView method:setItemTextColor(Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;)V. result: 0`

Comment: I was finally able to fix the issue. I had an unknown problem with Android Studio and R file. And you are right about `itemIconTintList`. Because Data Binding create auto setter it should be used instead of `itemIconTint` No need for custom BindingAdapter.

Thanks !